# Python2. Существующее соединение было принудительно закрыто удаленным узлом

Tags: python, python-2.x, request

Ошибка:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', 
error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote 
host'))
```

Сам код:

```
import requests, sys, os

with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\supportfile\\werewolves.txt") as werewolves:
            array = [row.strip() for row in werewolves]
bb = 'http://shost-craft.su\n'.join(array)

r = requests.get(bb, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 4.0) Opera 7.0 [en]"})
if r.status_code == 200:
    print('ok')
```

Почему у меня принудительно закрывается соединение? **В ФАЙЛЕ 15 САЙТОВ** на которые отправляется запрос.
Или с одного IP адреса нельзя запрос на более чем 5-10 адресов? Уже даже `headers` поставил, чтоб думало что я не бот.

Comment: после `bb = ...` добавьте `print bb`, и посмотрите, что получится. Если у Вас цель открыть несколько сайтов по очереди - надо вызывать `requests.get()` для каждой отдельной строки в цикле. Это для начала

Comment: вывелся список ссылок, но если у меня 2000 адресов то этого деалть крайне трудно, и очень много морочится, в одной программе тоже было так, так там нормально было и без ошибок

Comment: это не список ссылок. Это все ссылки в одной строке (метод `''.join()` объединяет всё в одну строку). Если мне не изменяет память, в requests.get() ссылки нужно передавать по одной. Кроме того, если нужно открывать много ссылок, есть смысл попробовать распараллелить запросы (только не злоупотребляя), например, с помощью `grequests`

Comment: тоесть мне нужно добавить \n .strip() в конце?

Comment: Вам не нужно делать `''.join()`. Нужно в цикле перебирать все строки, что есть в `array`, формировать из них нужный url (или что вы там делаете), и по одной передавать их в `requests.get()`. Кстати, а что в файле? Url должен быть вида `'http://shost-craft.su/+строка_из_файла`?

Comment: @stxdtm когда я вывожу список у меня все по отдельности, тоесть http://ex.com/google.com . Вот этим я и реализовал : array = [row.strip() for row in werewolves] row.strip() А с помощью grequests у меня не получается. Может попробовать с помощью urllib.request или urllib3 ? Они подойдут?

Comment: bb - это не список, это строка. `print type(bb)`. Покажите пример хотя бы одного url, к которому Вы хотите сделать запрос

Comment: @stxdtm Url должен быть виду https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://shost-craft.su . И я не совсем понял что вы имели ввиду перебирать все строки, можете скинуть пример кода, и может нужно использовать urllib.requests или urllib3?

Comment: Посмотрите ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests, sys, os

bb = 'http://shost-craft.su'

with open("C:\\cruelnetwork\\supportfile\\werewolves.txt") as werewolves:
    array = [row.strip()+bb for row in werewolves]

for url in array:
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 4.0) Opera 7.0 [en]"})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('ok')
```